# South how to migrate from ForeignKey to ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-south

How can i migrate from ForeignKey to ManyToMany?

Original model

```
class Campaign(TimeStampedModel):
    featured_review = models.ForeignKey(
        'reviews.Review',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='featured_on',
        default=None
    )
```

Modified model

```
class Campaign(TimeStampedModel):
    featured_review = models.ManyToManyField(
        'reviews.Review',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='featured_on',
        default=None
    )
```

When I run

```
./manage.py schemamigration companies --auto
```

I have "Nothing seems to have changed."

Comment: That would suggest to me that the fields are the same as far as the schema is concerned. Have you tried adding multiple relations to see if the application code change is enough?

Comment: This may be of interest...
http://blog.klymyshyn.com/2010/12/django-model-migrations-with-south-how.html

Comment: `Campaign` is not subclass of `django.db.models.Model`, is this just for posting the question or it is the actual definition?

Comment: @activehigh just for posting.

Comment: @GarryCairns i thought the same, but when i try to run it, the app fails with this DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'campaigns_featured_review' doesn't exist")

Comment: @IanPrice thanks!but i don't get the same results, the migration isn't created with south --auto